# Scrapy - Unable to get the right data from the table

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to pull the data from a particular table on this link -
https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/canara-robeco-blue-chip-equity-fund-direct-plan/portfolio-holdings/MCA212
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0is2.jpg)

The table ID in the HTML is - equityCompleteHoldingTable
Please refer to the screenshot above, and help in getting the stock data as a dictionary from the website table.

Thanks.

**What I tried**
In Scrapy Shell, I am trying the following commands -

scrapy shell 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/canara-robeco-blue-chip-equity-fund-direct-plan/portfolio-holdings/MCA212'

```
table = response.xpath('//*[@id="equityCompleteHoldingTable"]')
rows = table.xpath('//tr')
row =  rows[2]
row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract()
```

--- > **returns "No. of Stocks"**. Here the extracted data is coming from a different table on the above webpage.

I have found that the class that this table is using is used in other tables as well. And one of those tables i actually returning the data "No. of Stocks".

**What I expected**
I expected the data to come from the equityCompleteHoldingTable table (screenshot above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem is that you are not using relative xpath expressions.

For example `rows = table.xpath("//tr")` is an absolute xpath path.  Absolute paths are parsed from the root of the page, regardless of how deeply nested the selector is.

A relative path query starts parsing from the current selector element.  To use a relative xpath expression you only need to add a `.` as the very first character, similar to filesystem relative paths.  For example: `rows = table.xpath(".//tr")`

With that in mind you will probably have more luck with the following:

```
>>> table = response.xpath('//*[@id="equityCompleteHoldingTable"]')
>>> rows = table.xpath('.//tr')
>>> row = rows[2]
>>> row.xpath('.//td/text()').extract()[3:]
['Banks', '30.99', '8247.9', '9.34%', '0.14%', '9.69% ', '7.66% ', '86.56 L', '0.00 ', 'Large Cap', '75.79']
>>>
```

```py
In [1]: table = response.xpath('//*[@id="equityCompleteHoldingTable"]')

In [2]: rows = table.xpath('.//tr')

In [3]: row = rows[2]

In [4]: row.xpath('.//td//text()').getall()
Out[4]:
['\n                                                                                                            ',
 '\n                                                                                                        ',
 'ICICI Bank Ltd. ',
 '\n                                                ',
 'Banks',
 '30.99',
 '8247.9',
 '9.34%',
 '0.14%',
 '9.69% ',
 '(Aug 2022)',
 '7.66% ',
 '(Dec 2021)',
 '86.56 L',
 '0.00 ',
 'Large Cap',
 '75.79']

In [5]: cells = row.xpath('.//td//text()').getall()

In [6]: [i.strip() for i in cells]
Out[6]:
['',
 '',
 'ICICI Bank Ltd.',
 '',
 'Banks',
 '30.99',
 '8247.9',
 '9.34%',
 '0.14%',
 '9.69%',
 '(Aug 2022)',
 '7.66%',
 '(Dec 2021)',
 '86.56 L',
 '0.00',
 'Large Cap',
 '75.79']
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have an additional query - the data that is getting returned is starting from the 3rd column (even if I remove the 3: parameter, it returns on \n for the first 3. How do I get the data from the Stock Invested in column? Like "ICICI Bank Ltd." in rows[2]. My final aim is to get a dictionary item from this table. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: This works - row.xpath('.//td/*/a/text()').extract()). But how to get that the and other row data together (if it is possible). Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @LearningProductManagement try adding another `/` in front of the `text()`... so `row.xpath('.//td//text()')` that should work for all of them.

Comment: I added an example in my answer